# Removing sublists containing elements from another list's sublist

Tags: list-manipulation

Let there be two lists that have sublists:

```
a[] = {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}}
```

and

```
b[] = { {1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}}
```

I want to remove all those sublists in a[] that has elements contained in a sublist of b[]. So after removal I am expecting

```
a[] = {{2, 3, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}}.
```

I am not able to reach specific elements in a sublist. I can use a For loop for this, but it will slow down my program, so I want suggestions on a better *Mathematica* way of manipulating lists.

#### Edit

Sorry I guess my example was less than clear about what I am asking for. I want that any sublist in `a[]` that has all elements of any sublist from `b[]` shall be removed.

Comment: Are you sure you want to write `a[]` and `b[]`? You aren't defining functions or using indexing, so simple identifiers such as `a` and `b` would be better in your case.

Comment: ya actually they give same result.

Comment: Not under all circumstances. Consider `Clear[a]; a[] = 42; a = a[]; {a, a[]}`. This gives `{42, 42[]}` as its output. Is that what you would expect or would want?

Comment: thanks for correcting me precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Mathematica* supports the complement of a set:

```
Complement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}}]
   {{2, 3, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}}
```

---

For the elaborated version, you can use `Complement[]` in tandem with `DeleteCases[]`:

```
DeleteCases[{{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}}, 
            l_List /; Or @@ (Complement[#, l] === {} & /@ {{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}})]
   {{2, 3, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}}
```

Comment: I have amended my question..can you please look into it ?

Comment: You should've been explicit to begin with... wait.

Comment: Complement[#, l] === {} signifies what..can u someone explain how its working?

Comment: In the interest of teaching you how to fish: start by comparing the result of `Complement[#, {1, 2}] === {} & /@ {{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}}` and `Complement[#, {2, 3, 4, 4}] === {} & /@ {{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}}`

Answer (score 2):

In versions 10.2+, you can use `ContainsAll` combined with `Pick`, `Select`, `Cases` and `DeleteCases`:

```
Pick[a[], Nor @@ Through[(ContainsAll /@ b[])@#] & /@ a[]]
Select[a[], Nor @@ Through[(ContainsAll /@ b[])@#] &]
Cases[a[], _?(Nor @@ Through[(ContainsAll /@ b[])@#] &)]
DeleteCases[a[], _?(Or @@ Through[(ContainsAll /@ b[])@#] &)]
```

all give

> {{2, 3, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}}

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}};
b = {{1, 2}, {4, 5, 6}};


Pick[a, Nor @@@ Outer[SubsetQ, a, b, 1]]
```

> {{2, 3, 4, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 5}}